# Is it possible to use Ceylon with Maven and/or Gradle and/or SBT?

Tags: maven, gradle, sbt, ceylon

I see that Ceylon requires Ant and has its own build system.

Is it possible to compile Ceylon files inside common build tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://github.com/ceylon/ceylon-maven-plugin for information on the Maven plugin and https://github.com/renatoathaydes/ceylon-gradle-plugin for the Gradle plugin. Hope this helps!